# EXPDP - why is block estimate significantly larger than segment size?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, export, expdp

I'm exporting one specific table for a schema which I thought was a relatively small 5.4 GB

```
SQL>  select bytes/1024/1024 MB from user_segments where segment_name='TABLENAME';
       MB
----------
      5376
```

However, EXPDP estimates the export size to be over 8 times that size at 46 GB:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
Starting "SCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  SCHEMA/********@DATABASE dumpfile=TABLENAME_20211028.dmp tables=TABLENAME
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 45.87 GB
```

Why is the estimate so much larger than the "table size"?

Comment: Please provide the expdp sql which you triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the table may have LOB segments that have different names.

```
select column_name, segment_name from user_lobs where table_name = 'TABLENAME';
```

And you should check the size of those segments as well.

Comment: Got it, thank you